# Connect to a Mongo database in python

Tags: python, scrapy, pymongo

I have to do a crawler (I choose python) to fill a database create in a Symfony project (use doctrine).
The crawler is done, but when i try to fill the database it doesn't work ...

So I create a new table test in my db (mtdbdd), with just an auto-increment ID and a title. I try to fill with this code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

MONGO_URI = 'mongodb://root:root@127.0.0.1:8889'

client = MongoClient(connect=False)
client = MongoClient(MONGO_URI)
db = client.mtdbdd
coll = db.test

try:
    result = coll.insert_one({"title": "test"})
except coll.errors.OperationFailure as e:
    print e.code
    print e.details
```

But I have the error:

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: Got opcode 3945 but expected 1
```

Some one can help me ? thanks guys !

Comment: how do you start mongodb? Mongodb default port is 27017 usually, so not sure why you use 8889

Comment: change those 2 lines of MongoClient, to `MongoClient(MONGO_URI, connect=False)`

Comment: @MrE I use this port cause my database is on this port, shoud'nt I ? (I use Mamp on a mac)

Comment: @eLRuLL I try but it didn't work ... :/

Comment: You should cross check your username and password is `root`.  From the error, the client can't connect to the mongo server

Comment: @bastienlequéré if you SET it as this port, then sure. Not sure what this has to do with MAMP which is a MySQL based stack. Are you actually using MONGODB?

Comment: if you are using mongodb, did you change the default port to 8889? If not, mongodb is most certainly running on 27017.

Comment: check your port with network Utility in /System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/  click Port Scan and enter your IP 127.0.0.1 to scan. It should show you what ports are open and if your port 8889 is indeed open.'

Comment: Post the output of `sudo netstat -plant` from your machine to the question

Comment: @Mre yes the port 8889 is open: Open TCP Port:  8889   ddi tcp-2
But i don't change the default port of mongoDb ... i will try to do that

Comment: @TarunLalwani netstat don't have the option -plant in mac ^^

Comment: if port 8889 is what you think it is and 27017 is not showing up open, then it is probably right. before you start tryign to debug your script, i'd first try to connect with mongo shell https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/getting-started-with-the-mongo-shell/

Comment: Use `lsof -i 4 | grep LISTEN` then

Comment: Okay with the lsof -i the port 8889  is not open, but with the network app, he is ... I try to do the tuto @MrE, but i can't connect to my Db in mamp.
I think i let down MongoDb ...
Can I use an other tools in python, to fill my DB ?

Comment: Obvisouly, thanks for you're help guys, really ! :)

Comment: did you try port 27017?

Comment: @MrE yes but it did'nt connect to my DB ...

Comment: @MrE It connect to mongo, i see the connection but, it does not connect to my DB, who is already create by my symfony project, and i don't know how to do that ... :/

Comment: ah... yes of course: you're missing the DB name in the connection string
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/

Answer (score 0):

connections string should be of the form:

```
mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/

So in your case:

```
mongodb://root:root@127.0.0.1:8889/<dbname>
```

Get rid of

```
client = MongoClient(connect=False)
```

since you overwrite client on the next line anyway.